# is a space character considered empty when running mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

I've got a column in our database for invoice #'s.  When we ship out samples to customers, we do not "invoice" these shipments.  So instead of an invoice #, I just add a space.  This adds a "value" to the invoice_number column so that we know it is processed.

When running a simple select query with a condition  `WHERE invoice_number = '' OR invoice_nunber IS NULL`, invoices with a space are still returning.  I even tried it without the IS NULL condition.  It is only supposed to return items where NO invoice number has been assigned (WHERE SPACES COUNT AS AN INVOICE NUMBER).

So that brings me to my question, does mysql recognize a space as NOTHING or does it have a value?  Is there a better condition I can use instead of `WHERE invoice_number = ''` to only show TRUE empty results?

Comment: My main reason for posting is just intrigue at why spaces would be considered NOTHING and return as empty fields?

Comment: Basically “because MySQL decided to take liberties with things.” Just like ‘123abc’ is equal to 123 and so on.

Comment: is there a better condition I can run to detect spaces as spaces?

Comment: At least checking `length()` works but not sure if there’s something better available, haven’t had to do this myself

Comment: sami, I went ahead and added a `char_length()` function to the where clause and that did end up fixing my issue.  Please put your last comment as an answer and I will go ahead and accept it as it did resolve my issue.